# Get Top(N-1) records from a List

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I am selecting top 3 records from the Database. I want to display last 2 records except first record .How can we do this with C#. i am using asp.net 2.0 ,so cannot use linq .

Comment: what object/structure did you use to store those 3 records?

Comment: Can you post some code? How is the data formed after you get it out of the database? Is it in a DataSet, array, list, something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Won't it be:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
       string s = list[i];
    }
```

And if you are sure that it would always be the 2nd and 3rd items only, you can directly refer to them through the index value like:
`list[1]` and `list[2]`

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just index into the list. Assuming you have only 3 items in the list:

```
var item2 = list[1];
var item3 = list[2];
```

this will give you items 2 and 3. Unless if I misunderstood the question...

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
    DisplayData(dataStructure[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didnt see the "so cannot use linq " part

Add them to a List and use linq Skip

Something similar to

```
var allButFirst1 = waOrders.Skip(1);
```